# Why isn't my bath tub faucet serving hot water?

Tags: bathroom

I bought a house 2 years ago and I have noticed that the shower water is not as hot as it should be. The sink water is hot though and I'm pretty sure they are connected on the same hot water pipe but are somehow different in hot water. If I raise the water heater temp it does solve the issue but the sink water gets really hot. How can I fix this?

[image: sink photo]

[image: shower photo]

[image: thermometer showing sink water 132 degrees F]

[image: thermometer showing shower water 94 degrees F]

Comment: The shower might have an anti-scald valve that is wearing out or needs adjustment

Comment: You have a single control for hot/cold mix and amount of water. Those can go bad in a number of ways. In addition, there may be an anti-scald valve as part of it and *that* may be going bad. For example, if the control is messed up in a way that 100% hot actually gives you 80% hot/20% cold then the shower will always be a lot colder than the sink.

Comment: You need to open up the shower handle/valve and repair or replace it. i.e. clean it, and maybe a new cartridge or o-rings, or clean mineral deposits.

Comment: Further to @crip659's comment, some showers have an anti-scald valve you can override by pressing in a button.  These buttons can  jam or break internally